# #define USE_SQLDB (defined(USE_SQLITE) || defined(USE_MYSQL))

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015, `#define USE_SQLDB` directive doesn't do what I expect.
I have a minimal example to explain the issue

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define USE_SQLITE
//#define USE_MYSQL

#define USE_SQLDB (defined(USE_SQLITE) || defined(USE_MYSQL))

int main()
{
#if defined(USE_SQLITE)
    puts("SQLITE");             // OK
#endif

#if defined(USE_MYSQL)
    puts("MYSQL");              // Grayed out - OK
#endif

// Should expand to defined(USE_SQLITE) || defined(USE_MYSQL)
#if USE_SQLDB
    puts("SQLITE or MYSQL");    // Grayed out - NOT OK
#endif

#if defined(USE_SQLITE) || defined(USE_MYSQL)
    puts("SQLITE or MYSQL");    // OK
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the `USE_SQLDB` to be true, but it isn't.
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is simply not valid preprocessor stuff

```
#define USE_SQLDB (defined(USE_SQLITE) || defined(USE_MYSQL))
```

you are mixing c and preproc. You need

```
#if defined(USE_SQLITE) || defined(USE_MYSQL)
#define USE_SQLDB
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behavior: [Ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html)

> If the `defined` operator appears as a result of a macro expansion, the
>   C standard says the behavior is undefined.

and from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx):

> The `defined` directive can be used in an `#if` and an `#elif` directive,
>   but nowhere else.